# calling android api using html login button

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing android application. I want to write UI using html5 and internal API's using android API. I am using phone gap for that purpose. How can I call Andoid API's by clicking on login button which is created in html page. I don't want to call js for login purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create custom plugins [Apache Cordova plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html)